# Возможен ли порт ОС на реальные ПК? (MineOS)

Tags: lua, ос

Это, возможно, очень глупый вопрос, но возможно ли использовать эту ОС ([страничка GitHub](https://github.com/IgorTimofeev/OpenComputers)) для работы на реальных ПК?

*Не критикуйте жёстко, просто вдруг стало очень интересно.. И за мат все претензии только к создателю, прошу*

Comment: Все возможно, не понятно только зачем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, это будет непросто, но **в принципе** возможно (но зачем?..). Скорее всего, общая структура будет примерно такова:

1. Ядро (пусть даже linux).
2. Начальный процесс (init), который загружает драйвера и lua оболочку.
3. Всё остальное выносится в библиотеки, которые доступны из lua (а написаны на C/C++). Они, в свою очередь, могут использовать непосредственно API ядра аки системные вызовы (пусть и скрыто от пользователя, для которого существует лишь lua интерфейс): процессы, потоки, файлы и прочие прелести жизни.

Я рассматривал портирование не конкретной ОС, а OpenComputers системы в целом, то есть речь о запуске не только MineOS, но и прочих.